# Does a slow holomorphic function exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

**Backstory**. I was trying to come up with a function $f(z)$ that would have an essential singularity in $z = 0$ and would be limited by the following function with non-integer power (for some $\alpha$ and $A$):
\begin{equation}
|f(z)|\leq\frac{A}{|z|^\alpha},\ \alpha\in(0,1),\ 0<|z|<1.
\end{equation}

**The question**. Is there a function $f(z):\ O_r(\infty) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in some viscinity $O_r(\infty)\subset\mathbb{C}$ of the infinity and
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{f(z)}{z}=0$$
whilst
$$\nexists\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)$$
?

Referring to the backstory, $f(\frac{1}{z})$ should then satisfy the original inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a function does not exist. $|f(z)|\leq\frac{A}{|z|^\alpha}$ with $ \alpha\in(0,1)$ implies that
$$
 \lim_{z \to 0} z f(z) = 0
$$
and then [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) implies that $f$ has a *removable singularity* at $z=0$.